# Lowest possible value of a function with derivative greater than 2

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

I have the following two problems, and want to attempt to solve them with Mathematical rigour(which I don't yet possess):

> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $[1,4]$ and is such that $f(1) = 10$ and $f' \geq 2$ on $[0,4]$. Find the lowest possible value of $f(4)$

Logic: $f(1) = 10$ and $f' \geq 2$, so we have an increase of minimum $6$ hence, $f(4)\geq 16$

Rigour: $f(1) = 10$ and $f' \geq 2$, so  to have minimum increase, we have the take the lowest possible $f'$, hence $f' = 2$ and $f(x) = 2x + 8$, so $f(4) = 16$.

Not sure if this is even close to rigourous.

> Give a function $f$ which is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and which has the following three properties, or explain why such a function cannot exist: $f(0) = -1, f(2) = 4$ and $f'(x) \leq 2$ for all $x$

Logic: It isn't possible as we are increasing by $5y$ in $2x$ which has a greater derivative than 2, thus breaking property three.

Rigour: $f(0) = -1$ has $y = kx+c$ at $(0,-1)$ we have $-1=c$ and with $(2,4)$ we obtain $4 = 2k - 1$, $k = 2.5$ and therefore $f(x) = 2.5x - 1$ and thus $f'(x) = 2.5$, since $2.5 \not\leq 2$, no such function exists.

Could either of these answers be accepted as rigorous?

Comment: I would imagine that a real analysis class would want to see the mean value theorem mentioned on a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first bit

BY mean value theorem, $$\frac{f(4)-f(1)}{3}=f'(\alpha)$$ for some $\alpha \in (1,4)$

Now since $f'(x) \gt 2$ for all $x $ on $[0,4]$, we have $$f(4)-f(1) \ge 6 \implies f(4) \ge 6+10=16 $$

For the second bit similraly, $$\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2}=f'(\alpha)$$, for some $\alpha \in (0,2)$

Then Since $f'(x) \le 2$ for all $x$ , we have $5 \le 4$, which is not possible

Comment: All answers here were good, but this covered both of them. I am surprised I forgot MVT! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

For a rigorous answer you need to use Mean Value theorem. By MVT there exists $c \in [1,4]$ such that
$$\frac{f(4)-f(1)}{4-1}=f^{'}(c).$$
But we are given that $f^{'}(c) \geq 2$, therefore
$$f(4)-f(1) \geq 6.$$
Thus the minimum value of $f(4)$ is $f(1)+6.$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be rigorous, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$f(4) = f(1) + \displaystyle\int_1^4 f'(x)\,dx \ge 10 + \int_1^4 2\,dx = 16$.

Equality holds iff $f'(x) = 2$ for all $x \in [1,4]$ and $f(1) = 10$.

Comment: They probably only have this for $f$ which are continuously differentiable in a real analysis class like this.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ differentiable and $f' \geq 2$ on $[0,4]$ gives $f(4)-f(1) = \int_1^4 f'(t) \mathrm{d}t \geq \int_1^4 2 \mathrm{d}t = 6$.  Thus, $f(4) \geq f(1)+6 = 10+6=16$.  This is direct application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Use the same method for your second question.